# Unable to submit form using admin post wordpress

Tags: forms

I have been facing a problem in wordpress. I have a form as below

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="input_name" id="inputName" placeholder="Name*"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control required" name="input_email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email*"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="download_catalog"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" name="input_mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And i have added the admin post hook in my functions.php as

```
add_action('admin_post_download_catalog','download_catalog');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_download_catalog','download_catalog');
function download_catalog() {
   print_r($_POST);wp_die();
}
```

But every time I submit the form it redirects to search results page.

I have also tested by updating the permalink and also deactivating plugins. Nothing happened it redirects to `domain/home/s?=` . Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: I would first try to Flush all redirects/Cookies from Browser to be sure nothing is cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is a tricky thing to achieve. You don't want the users to see it and make them do extra work.

This is way browsers try to cache as much as a reasonable thing they need to do.

### 301 Redirects

This type of redirect is cached by browsers.

> 301 Moved Permanently. A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which
>   passes between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) to the redirected
>   page. 301 refers to the HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In
>   most instances, the 301 redirect is the best method for implementing
>   redirects on a website.
>   [Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

### Cookies

Most time include pieces of content specific to the current user

### Local storage

Not so much used by applications but can have data necessary to function-specific parts of web apps.

## Solutions

The first try will be to Deactivate plugins and also remove redirects in the `.htaccess`.

Flushing WordPress rewrite rules.

> Flushing the rewrite rules is an expensive operation, there are
>   tutorials and examples that suggest executing it on the 'init' hook.
>   This is bad practice. It should be executed either on the 'shutdown'
>   hook, or on plugin/theme (de)activation.
>   [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Clear Cache and Cookies